# MySQL Selecting data in a many-to-many relationship (I think)

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a MySQL Table called contacts. It looks something like this:

```
+----------+
|contacts  |
+----------+
|id: int   |
|name: vc  |
|rank: int |
+----------+
```

The 'rank' is a foreign key mapped to a table called ranks that looks something like this:

```
+--------+
|ranks   |
+--------+
|id: int |
|name: vc|
+--------+
```

I did a sql query that looks like this, in the hopes that I would get a rank for every user, but it only gives me the first user that matches a rank:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.rank, r.name as rank_name FROM contacts c 
INNER JOIN ranks r ON r.id=c.rank
```

It seems to me that this would be the correct SQL statement to get a list of contacts that also contains their respective rank name. However, I only ever get back one contact per rank, and it's always the first contact (if sorted by contact.id).

Any solutions? Maybe I am missing something entirely too easy. I don't know.

Thanks!

## Edit

Per request, here are some of the rows:

```
Table: ranks
id      name
6       Primary
7       Secondary
10      Test

Table: contacts
id      name        rank
1       Joe         6
2       Jane        6
3       Mike        7
4       Adam        10
5       Edna        7
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks good, but the problem could be with your data. Can you verify your data, show us some of the records?

In particular the problem could be that not each rank (or contact) has an appropriate number in the other table.

Answer (score 0):

Is your SQL Client including a LIMIT 1,1?

By using INNER JOIN you're going to get only the rows that exist in both tables (i.e. match) If you want to get the rankless contacts you may use LEFT JOIN.

Comment: I've done a manual SQL query with LIMIT 0,100. This still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a many to many relationship, as you only map 1 rank to 0 or more contacts.

The query that is exactly like that should work. Could you provide us with some more data like what's in the exact query and what data is in your tables?

**EDIT**:
The data looks fine. Are you using a

```
GROUP BY rank.id
```

In your exact query?

Comment: No. I am using that exact query in my statement. It gives me Joe, Mike and Adam as my result set. I am just utterly confused by the whole mess.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem here. What do you get when you do:

    SELECT c.id, c.name, c.rank, c.rank FROM contacts c